# R error message for unused argument (writexl)

Tags: r, writexl

I have simple code

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dataset, "C:/adhoc/my_data.xlsx")
```

The above works, however when I try

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dataset, "C:/adhoc/my_data.xlsx", append=TRUE)
```

I get an unused argument error. How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation `?write_xlsx` there is not an `append` argument defined for this function, thus the error.  It has been raised as a [possible feature for that package](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/29) and deemed not possible.  You could read the spreadsheet, do the appending in R, and then re-write the full version.

Alternatively, perhaps you would be served by `write.xlsx()` from the `xlsx` package which *does* have this argument and might be suitable for your purposes?